# Laravel 5.5 Auth::Attempt with a Wordpress Table - Undefined index: password

Tags: php, laravel

I am really struggling getting an login attempt to work on Laravel 5.5…
I’m using a Wordpress Table(user_login, user_pass) with the default WP password hash.
To check the passwords I am using “MikeMcLin\WpPassword\Facades\WpPassword”

It fails on the “->attempt”, I’ve been trying many different solutions such as “->login”, but I can’t find one that works.

Anyone got any possible solution ideas please?

```
$user = Landlord::where('user_login', $request['username']) -> first();
 //dd($user['ID']);
   $foo = Landlord::find($user['ID']);
   $foo->getAuthPassword();
   //dd($foo);
   if(WpPassword::check($request['password'], $foo['user_pass'])){
     $user = array(
        'user_login' => $request['username'],
        'user_pass' => $foo['user_pass']
    );
     if(Auth::guard('landlord')->attempt($user, false)){
       dd('yay');
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the query and the password hash check yourself, just log them in. You are doing what the guard and the user provider would be doing for you with `attempt` anyway.

Check if you actually have the `$user` after line one ... do the hash check .. then just call `$guard->login($userModel)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "Undefined variable: guard", I have `protected $guard = 'landlord';` in my Landlord Model.

I have tried using `Auth::guard('landlord')->login($user, false)` but it just fails.